# require 'use-package: cannot load file on second time as per flycheck

Tags: use-package, load-path

For my `require 'use-package`, I'm getting `cannot load file` error but I really don't understand why.

In my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file, at the very top, I have

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(load (expand-file-name
         "load-path" (file-name-directory load-file-name)) nil t)
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "lisp" user-emacs-directory))
(load-library "init-emacs00")
```

However, in my `init-emacs00` file, at the very top, I too have

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

What strange is that my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file doesn't have such error, while my `init-emacs00.el` file does, as per `flycheck`:

[image]

It seems my above adding `"lisp"` into `load-path` has done something bad, but I don't know elisp except copying from working code thus I don't know how to fix the problem, I just want to add `~/.emacs.d/lisp/` to my `load-path`, where all my elisp resides, including my `init-emacs00.el` file.

That means, although it seems my above adding `"lisp"` is the problem, but they (all my elisp files) just load fine.

Also, I tried to add `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` to `load-path` myself, where the `use-package` is installed:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
  (require 'use-package))
```

[image]

but as we can see, that isn't working either.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to db48x's help on how to find the current value of the variable, I found that,

- `user-emacs-directory`’s value is `"~/.emacs.d/"`
- and my `load-path` value already contains `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` and `~/.emacs.d/elpa/use-package-20210207.1926`, when I took the above screenshots.

which makes the above `flycheck` warning very confusing.

Comment: Wht is the value of `user-emacs-directory`? Is there a `lisp` directory underneath that? Is the file `init-emacs00` in there? BTW, it should probably be called `init-emacs00.el` although that does not affect whether it will be found or not.

Comment: See my update in OP @NickD, thanks

Comment: To find the current value of the variable, type `C-h v`, then type the name of the variable (in this case `user-emacs-variable`), and hit enter. It would also be useful to know the value of `load-path` after you got done with it.

Comment: See my update in OP @db48x, thanks